Pari/gp no matching function
I'm trying to configure pari to use on C++.
Here's a code example showcasing my issue:
#include <pari/pari.h>

GEN d_field;
d_field = cgeti(5);
GEN upperLimit = exp(sqrt(log(d_field)));

Along with other similar errors for exp and sqrt, the compiler outputs: error: no matching function for call to ‘log(long int*&)’. VS code also highlights those functions. Curiously enough, GEN, cget etc. work just fine.  What am I doing wrong? I installed pari through apt-get.
in my CMakeList file I have:
...
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror -O0 -g -lpari -lm)
...
find_library(PARI_LIBRARY pari)
target_link_libraries(${TName}_${entry_point_name} ${PARI_LIBRARY})

What have I messed up?
I tried changing the flags in CMakeLists and looked online for a solution but couldnt find any problem similar to the one I'm experiencing.

Is the code really outside a function? Are you compiling for C or C++? They can have different rules so you should choose which one you are using.

what is log ? why you expect it to be declared? Is it from pari/pari.h ?

exp, sqrt and log are all part of the mathematical library. You need to include the "cmath" header.

The code isn't outside the function no lol, kinda forgot to add it to my example... I'm compiling for C++ which might be why this happens. I want to use exp, sqrt and log from the pari library.

Pari is a C library, which does not support multiple functions with the same name. You should look at the Pari documentation and use one of the correct functions from paridecl.h.
I think the following functions can be composed, but you will have to figure out what precision you want:
GEN     gexp(GEN x, long prec);
GEN     glog(GEN x, long prec);
GEN     gsqrt(GEN x, long prec);


How can I do this? I have experience in C and C++ but we didn't use C libraries in our C++ course so I assumed it'd work in a similar manner where I can include the pari header and just use all functions.

By changing the name of the function you call (log,sqrt,exp) to something else. See edit.
